# How to get a facebook page access token without getting my app reviewed?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I am trying to fetch the latest Facebook posts from our company's page to show them on our website. It already worked until a few weeks ago, Facebook unfortunately changed some of their security guidelines. Initially I sended some requests to the Facebook Graph API using PHP, the App ID, the App Secret and the User Token to create an page accesstoken and fetch my company's posts.

Thanks to the new guidelines new created Apps do not have the "manage_pages" permission you need to create an page accesstoken. To recieve this permission you have to get your App reviewed by Facebook which seems quite laborious to me.

Can you think of another way to fetch my posts? I mean those are posts from a page I created. I do not really understand why there are so many security issues.

Thanks!

Comment: I still can fetch public posts from any page without any permissions https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=9445547199%3Ffields%3Dposts&version=v2.8

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to get your app reviewed, if it is not intended to be used by the general public.

App Development FAQ: [My app is only used by a small number of people, who are all listed in the Role section of the App Dashboard - do I need to go through Login Review?](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_180362122361921)

> No, it does not have to be reviewed. If your app is only used by a very limited number of people […] it's completely normal to list them all as having different roles in your app's dashboard. They can be listed as Admins, Developers or Testers

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?..." to fetch just posts from my own pages I am now using following URL to fetch any public posts:

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/{PAGE-ID or PAGE NAME}?fields=
name,picture,feed.limit(100){full_picture,created_time,message,likes,
comments,type,link}&access_token={USERTOKEN}"
```